# Why are WZW models interesting?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I realise this is a very broad question, but when I was studying for my thesis I came across [WZW models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wess%E2%80%93Zumino%E2%80%93Witten_model) a few times and I never quite understood them.

So, I understand that these models describe strings propagating on a group manifold $G$ which is subjected by gravity and the $B$-field. These models are conformally invariant and allow for compactifications.

But what is the physical application of these models for string theory? Why would spacetime (or a more abstract target space) be a group manifold?
Or should I just see them as certain building blocks for type II string theories from which we could 'learn a lot'?

(I'm just looking for a simple physical motivation for studying these models.)

Comment: I don't know much about WZW but I do know of one application: Witten's solution of Chern-Simons theory depends on it. In particular, Witten showed that if $M$ is a three manifold with boundary a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ and $G$ a group then the Hilbert space of the Chern-Simons theory on $M$ with group $G$, based on $\Sigma$ is the space of conformal blocks of the WZW model on $\Sigma$ with group $G$. This is connected to string theory since Chern-Simons shows up at all kinds of places in string theory (through "large N duality" in particular).

Answer (score 2):

A more "pedestrian" application is that the low-energy physics of a Heisenberg antiferromagnetic spin chain is described by a WZW theory.  This is a very simple and concrete model which has been shown to accurately describe many real materials.  See for example
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9802014v1, http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5421v1, or section 7.10 of Fradkin's book.